# Courier gave me a letter that I already had

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have a bug with the courier, he gave me a letter from a friend that I already have. So I have 2 of the same letter in my inventory. I tried to read it, but the quest didn't start.

I dropped both letters and tried to read them from the ground but still nothing was activated.

Instead of loading the save and talking with him again, I thought he soon will gives me another letter, but it has been over 10 hours of gameplay and still nothing. How can I fix this?

Letters are about word of power in Rannveig's Fast.

Answer (score 1):

Those two letters have nothing to do with what you received from the courier.

If those letters are genuinely new, then by the time you opened them, a new quest will have popped up, telling you to search out the new word.

To confirm that, look in both your active and completed quest list and see if the location mention in both letters are in your quest log (they should both be there, at least one would be completed, and possibly both).

Those letters can be dumped after being read. If, for some odd reason, you want to keep a corpse around and not disappear, you can dump the letter in the corpse to preserve it.